# Count Models for Continuous variables

Tags: regression, dataset, poisson-distribution, continuous-data

I want to analyze the effect of taxes on the amount of fixed assets an affiliate of an multinational capitalizes.

Fixed assets are of course not a count variable. Can I anyway use a count model such as poisson to estimate the effect?

My dependet variable is very skewed

Thankful for any help.

Comment: If you know the variable isn't a count, why do you want to use a count model?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that my dependet variabl is very skewed. Therefore, it's from my point of view the only possibility I have. All other models do not work.

Comment: What about log-transformation?

Comment: Dozens of skewed distributions have been studied. It isn't just the shape of the distribution but the relationship of the parameters that define the distribution, for example a link between the peak value and the standard deviation.

Comment: problem with log is that there still would be heteroskedasticity. But what would be the flaw if I use a count model?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use a count model.  Instead, use a model that does not assume that the residuals are normal.  One such model is quantile regression. There are also various robust regression methods that relax this assumption.